# How threading.timer works in python

Tags: python, multithreading

I want to run a function every `n` seconds. After some research, I figured out this code:

```
import threading

def print_hello():
    threading.Timer(5.0, print_hello).start()
    print("hello")

print_hello()
```

Will a new thread be created every 5 sec when `print_hello()` is called?

Comment: No, same thread will be used

Comment: @VivekKumar - no, a new thread is created for each timer event. `Timer` is a subclass of `Thread`.

Comment: @tdelaney Ohk. I looked at https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Timer and inferred that its a single thread which will execute repeatedly

Comment: @VivekKumar the `threading.Timer` instance is a single instance which represents a single thread. It can be made to run repetitive code, if the function it calls contains a loop. However, as explained in that documentation link, `print_hello` will only be called once by the `threading.Timer` object. Multiple threads are created because `print_hello` *creates a new instance* each time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Timer` is a thread. Its created when you instantiate `Timer()`. That thread waits the given amount of time then calls the function. Since the function creates a new timer, yes, it is called every 5 seconds.

Comment: Won't this fail after about 1000 iterations or so, due to Pythons recursion stack?

Comment: @kebman Not in this case. `print_hello` reschedules itself to be run again in the future and then returns. It didn't call itself again so it is not recursive. `threading.Timer(5.0, print_hello).start()` just hands the `print_hello` function object to the timer and says call me again in 5.

Answer (score 0):

Little indentation of code would help to better understand the question.

Formatted Code:

```
from threading import Timer

def print_hello():
    Timer(5.0,print_hello,[]).start()
    print "Hello"

print_hello()
```

This code works spawning a new thread every 5 sec as you are calling it recursively in every new thread call.

Comment: Thanks for indentation. I am not sure how stackoverflow works and if I can ask follow- up questions. But, Can I achieve the same without creating new threads?

Comment: Yes.. You can continue here in the comments or edit the original post question citing: PS: OK I got this..but now m stuck here..

Comment: And you can always upvote the response which answers your question

Comment: Okay then! So is there a way to run a function periodically without creating new threads?

Comment: For parallelism you can use thread pools (group of pre-instantiated, idle threads) as described [https://www.metachris.com/2016/04/python-threadpool/] here. But for periodic execution timer threads are way to go